# Want to count each individual employee's presents and absents

Tags: mysql, sql

i've created a employee attendance table having 3 columns emp_name, emp_present & date,

there is no primary key in mytable

i'm using this query to get total presents of employees

```
  SELECT `emp_name`, `emp_present`,(select sum(emp_present='present') 
  from empattendance) as 'total presents', `date` FROM `empattendance` where date=curdate()
```

but i want to get total presents and 'total absents' of each indiviual shown with them in total presents and 'total absents' column respectively. I'm a newbie in database and don't have much knowledge about how to sort this problem.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation, to get the count of rows where employee was present and the count of rows where employee was absent like this:

```
SELECT emp_name, 
  SUM(emp_present = 'present') AS numPresence, 
  SUM(emp_present = 'absent') AS numAbsence
FROM employees
GROUP BY emp_name;
```

---

EDIT:

If you want a running total of presence and absences, you'll need to use a variable:

```
SET @present := 0;
SET @absent := 0;
SELECT emp_name, dateColumn, 
   IF(emp_present = 'present', @present := @present + 1, @present) AS numPresence
   IF(emp_present = 'absent', @absent := @absent+ 1, @absent) AS numAbsense
FROM myTable
ORDER BY dateColumn;
```

Comment: the query is missing a group by clause.

Comment: it only returned me one employees record

Comment: @ShaheryarBhatti try with the edited solution, I made a typo.

Comment: it's giving me same numpresence and numabsence and when i used the
'where date=curdate()' condition it returned me both(presence & absence)
equal to '1'

Comment: Do you have two rows where an employee was present and absent on the same day?

Comment: nope... i solved the same numpresence and numabsence problem by sum() function but i still need to show current day absence or presence...

Comment: Good catch, I meant to use sum. Didn't realize my error, I don't have any data to test with. I'm not sure what you mean, can you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: i wanted to upload pictures but since i'm new this site won't allow me to upload any image...

Comment: nope.. don't know how to use it... can i email you the pics??

Comment: You can learn how to use SQL Fiddle, or look at other SQL questions to see how you can format sample data inside the question itself. Otherwise, I can't determine why this won't work. What do you mean 'show current day absence or presence'?

Comment: So like a running total?

Comment: @ShaheryarBhatti I have edited with a solution. I'm unable to test it, but I think it will help you.

Comment: @ShaheryarBhatti no problem, I'm glad I could help. If this is the answer you stick with, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers know what solved your problem.